# Why is curl failing when it is run through Java?

Tags: java, curl

I am trying to post data to an external web-service through java. I have tried going through an HttpsURLConnection but I have been getting a genereric internal_error message on the handshake and ran out of suggestions on google to try to fix it.

I have tested with the equivalent cURL script and it succeeded without issue. In order to test it more thoroughly, I added the same script in Java using a Process to execute it. However, the same issue is persisting. Prior to running it through the process, I output the entire cURL string and tested that it still ran, which it did successfully. However, when running through Java it fails saying that it couldn't resolve host and then shows the token string and a different.

This is the curl script with sensitive info replaced:

```
curl -v -X POST %URL_HERE%
-H 'Accept: */*' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer %LONG_STRING_HERE%' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data "@/Path/to/folder/file/Data_ee801ae52060.json"
```

It then gives the following error:

```
* About to connect() to * port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for Bearer:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'Bearer'
* Closing connection #0

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Bearer'
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for %TOKEN_STRING_HERE%':80
* Couldn't resolve host '%TOKEN_STRING_HERE%''
* Closing connection #0

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '%PARTIAL_TOKEN_STRING_HERE%.
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for application:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'application'
* Closing connection #0

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'application'...
```

Prior to this error, it shows that it is using port 443.
Can any of you think of a reason why this would be occurring?

Comment: Well which port is the content on? 443 or 80?

Comment: This happens because your Java code is wrong. You are trying to run a shell command without a shell.

Comment: It succeeds when CURL runs on 443

Comment: The port number is just a symptom of the underlying problem. You are trying to run a shell command without a shell, which causes cURL to receive a wrong set and number of arguments. It misinterprets these extra/wrong arguments as URLs and tries to access them on the default port 80. The solution is not to continue to give it wrong arguments while trying to convince it to use port 443 instead. The solution is the give it correct arguments, either by invoking the shell command in a shell, or rewrite it to execve semantics. If you would like help with your Java code, please consider posting it.

Comment: To any looking at this later, I swapped to a ProcessBuilder and it called the process correctly

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using PostMan https://www.getpostman.com/ which offer a feature to automatically convert curl to java as well as other languages .

here is tutorial on using that feature : https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/

here is the generate output using OkHttp for your example:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "@/Path/to/folder/file/Data_ee801ae52060.json");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("%URL_HERE%")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("Accept", "/")
  .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer %LONG_STRING_HERE%")
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```